# Whats is the meaning of "pq"?

Tags: variance

When we are talkng about a binomial distribution

I can understand the meaning of np (that it is the mean), cause we assign a "absolute value", for what it is a "relative value", (the probability of succes, 0 to 1.00)

but when we are referring to the equation of variance

npq = variance.

Is there a way to interpret "pq", in the same way that we can interpet, "np"?

Comment: $q$ here must be $1-p$

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thank you for you answers, yes I know that q is 1-p, that it means the probability of failure but what I would like to know is the meaning of "pq"

Comment: $pq$ means p multiplied by q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of n Bernoulli(p) random variables is a binomial(n, p) random variable.

$p \cdot q = p \cdot (1-p)$ the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) of a Bernoulli random variable with a mean of p. Variance is a measure of dispersion, meaning it is a measure of how far a set of numbers is spread out from their average value. It is maximized when $p=q = \frac{1}{2}$, so failure and success are equally likely:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @dimitriy !!