# Why sample size calculation for ratio-based metric doesn't consider the standard deviation of the ratio

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, sample-size, sample

When calculating sample size for ratio-based metrics like CTR or Purchase Rate, it appears that one doesn't need to consider the standard deviation of the ratio metrics.

I tried calculators like https://www.statsig.com/calculator, or code in Statsmodel

```
print(NormalIndPower().solve_power(
    effect_size=effect_size,
    nobs1=None,
    alpha=0.05,
    power=0.8,
    ratio=1.0,
    alternative='two-sided'
)）
```

Does it make no difference if the metric varies a lot or varies little?

Comment: The rate pins down the variance. Example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/601693/7071).

Comment: I understand the rate pins down the variance of the Bernoulli distribution, but couldn't wrap my mind around the variance across time interval across the time axis

Comment: You can think of each time a potential buyer shows up as another trial. A wider time window means more trials. It is true that metrics that add up become more variable with longer windows. So longer tests get you more users but more variance in the outcome.

Comment: thanks @dimitriy. when comparing two rates both the same time interval, say weekly, would it naturally follow that the one with lower ratio tend to have higher variance week-to-week? if not then the ratio requiring lower sample could have higher week-to-week variance which seems contradictory